# Read Checkboxvalues that were dynamically created in a Datatable c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, datatable

I have this code that dynamically created my checkboxes.  I have several columns of checkboxes and several rows, so it needs to be totally dynamical.

I don't know how i can read the values of the checkboxes and would like to ask for some help. BTW I would like to save the values in a multidimensional array.

```
Meldungtable.Columns.Add("Warnungen", typeof(string));

  for (int meldungcnt = 0; meldungcnt < SPSWarnungsBausteinArray.Length; meldungcnt++)
  {
    Meldungtable.Rows.Add(SPSWarnungsBausteinArray[meldungcnt]);
  }
  WarnungenDataGridView.DataSource = Meldungtable;

  for (int kameracnt = 1; kameracnt <= Kameraanzahl; kameracnt++)
  {
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Kamerachk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    Kamerachk.HeaderText = "Kamera" + kameracnt;
    Kamerachk.Name = "KameraChkBox" + kameracnt;
    Kamerachk.Width = 70;
    WarnungenDataGridView.Columns.Add(Kamerachk);
  }
```

I would read row by row and check for the checkbox name, that i have assigned before, but as I am reading the data in a different method I don't think this works out.

Please help

Display:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in WarnungenDataGridView.Rows)
  {
    for (int col = 1; col < WarnungenDataGridView.ColumnCount; col++)
    {
      //DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[col];
      WarnungenDataGridView.Rows[row.Index].Cells[col].Value = "true";

    }
  }
```

Comment: why would you not do a foreach on the dataridview's checkbox to see if it's selected or not.. I will post an example for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in WarnungenDataGridView.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell CheckedCell = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell; 

    if (CheckedCell.Value != null)
    {
        if (CheckedCell.Value == CheckedCell.TrueValue)
        {
           //It's checked! do something within your code where necessary 
        }  
    }              
}
```

Comment: you can also do whatever you want from there, use the debugger so you can see all of the properties of the `row` variable to determine what you want to do in regards to header, number of checkboxes that are checked etc..

Comment: okay if i want to read several columns and rows i just go with a for loop for the columns?

Comment: Okay it all worked out thank you very much!!
The other problem I face i loading the value into the checkbox - I want to display whether the checkbox is checked or not upon load.
THis is what i've tried but it doesn't display anything: "for the code please take a look at the edit of the question"

Comment: Glad I could help @JenniferR